# How to call init() method of a controller by default in all actions

Tags: php, zend-framework3

```
class IndexController extend AbstractActionController
{
    construct__()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $exp = 'exemple';
        $this->view->setVariable('exp', $exp);
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // I Want call init in all action without $this->init();
    }

    public function aboutAction()
    {
        // I Want call init in all action without $this->init();
    }
}
```

I want call function `init()` by default on all actions of this controller without manually typing `$this->init()`

Comment: What kind of processing do you want to perform in that `init()` method? Is there any reason to not do it in the constructor?

Comment: return viewModel

Comment: Perhaps it would be enough to define one action and point to it in all affected routes? (`<routeName>.options.defaults.action` parameter)

Comment: i dont understand what you mean please give me example code thank's

Comment: You want to call init() method before or after __construct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
// I find solution in my question 
//thanks for all peopole that they help me 

class indexController extends AbstractController{

public function __construct()
{
$this->init();
}

protected function init()
{
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->setVariaa*ble($tt,'message')

return $view;
}

public function indexAction()
{
return $view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume that your routes are defined like the following (`module.config.php`):

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;

return [
    // …
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'about' => [
                'options' => [
                    'defaults' => [
                        'action'     => 'about',
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class
                    ],
                    'route' => '/about'
                ],
                'type' => Literal::class
            ],
            'home' => [
                'options' => [
                    'defaults' => [
                        'action'     => 'index',
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class
                    ],
                    'route' => '/'
                ],
                'type' => Literal::class
            ]
        ]
    ]
    // …
];
```

As you can see, `about` and `home` routes point to different actions, while you want them to do the same thing, that is call the `IndexController::init()` method. But you can simply make both routes point to the same action and, in result, do the same thing in one method instead of calling `IndexController::init()`.

Let’s simplify your `IndexController` — remove all methods and add a single `commonAction`:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function commonAction()
    {
        // perhaps do other things
        return new ViewModel(['exp' => 'exemple']);
    }
}
```

Now you can go back to `module.config.php` and instruct the router to use `commonAction` for both `about` and `home` routes. Just replace both

```
'action' => 'about'
```

and

```
'action' => 'index'
```

with

```
'action' => 'common'
```

Comment: what do you mean about  : make both routes point to the same action and, in result, do the same thing in one method instead of calling IndexController::init().

Comment: Instead of calling `init` in both actions, create a single action that would contain all the logic that you wanted to place in that `init` method. Assuming that you want to do the same in all actions.

Comment: ok , I understand that ,how can  instruct the router to use commonAction for both about and home routes?.

Comment: Follow my answer. Replace `'action' => 'about'` with `'action' => 'common'` and `'action' => 'index'` with `'action' => 'common'`.

Comment: i dont want change route that not what i'm loking for ,  thanks